# Angular Nested Dynamically Components

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to create components dynamically from given json. The first level is TestComponent who can have many TestLayerComponent. The problem is that TestLayerComponent also can have many TestLayerComponents. I use this to make slide push menu dynamically. If Layer path starts with Europe create `<li>` with text Europe, if Europe have Balkans create new `<ul>` in Europe with `<li>` Balkans and etc.

The menu must look [like this](https://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/demo/responsive/responsive.html) but implement with components not with DOM.

```
    [{
  Username:"",
  Password:"",
  Maps:[
    {
    Name:"",
    Title:"",
    Layers:[
       id:""
       path:"Europe/Balkans/Greece"
     ]
   },

    {
    Name:"",
    Title:"",
    Layers:[
       id:""
       path:"Europe/Balkans/Romania"
     ]
   },
  {
    Name:"",
    Title:"",
    Layers:[
       id:""
       path:"Asia/China"
     ]
   },
  ]

}
]
```

Here is my code that I try but still display only last component.

```
for (const map of maps) {
  mapViewContainerRef.clear();
  let mapRow = mapViewContainerRef.createComponent(mapFactory);
  mapRow.instance.maps = map;
  for (const layer of map.layers) {
    mapFactory = this.menuFactory.resolveComponentFactory(TestLayerComponent);
    mapViewContainerRef.clear();
    mapViewContainerRef.createComponent(mapFactory);
    mapRow = mapViewContainerRef.createComponent(mapFactory);
    mapRow.instance.layers = layer;
  }
  mapRow.destroy();
}
```

Comment: tried the code bleow?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const map of maps) {
  mapViewContainerRef.clear();
  let mapRow = mapViewContainerRef.createComponent(mapFactory);
  let index = 1;
  mapRow.instance.maps = map;
  for (const layer of map.layers) {
    mapFactory = this.menuFactory.resolveComponentFactory(TestLayerComponent);
    mapRow = mapViewContainerRef.createComponent(mapFactory, index);
    mapRow.instance.layers = layer;
    index++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok but TestComponent now is not showing and layer must be inside TestComponent.I use directive <ng-template appAddMapToMenu>

Comment: No it's work only for TestLayerComponent.How can I move TestLayer inside TestComponent programaticaly or add TestLayerComponent to Test

Comment: you want test later component inside testcomponent?

Comment: hmmmm like you have mapViewContainerRef, do you have any such containerref inside TestComponent.

Comment: You can see here in my website the left slider menu.Thsi is the structure that I need.But now I have only two rows. https://vladimirpetukhov.github.io/resume-app

Comment: hmmmm like you have mapViewContainerRef, do you have any such containerref inside TestComponent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214593/discussion-between-aakash-garg-and-dotnetdeveloper).